# Profiling information shows a visualforce method executed for 35,256 ms. But the APEX CPU Limit is 10,000 ms

Tags: apex, managed-package, governorlimits, cpulimit

[image: Execution Overview]

In the Execution logs, Profiling information shows a managed package visualforce method executed for 35,256 ms. But the APEX CPU Limit is 10,000 ms. How is that possible.

PS. I am debugging APEX CPU Timeout Issue. My managed package is dependent on another vendor's managed package.

Comment: I've [explained this before](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/48648#49351), as well as [Derek F](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/123171#123173). Basically, the system can choose when, or if, to terminate your request at its discretion based on available resources. It's unlikely, but possible, that a transaction could run as high as 30,000 ms. You'll probably need to get managed package debugging enabled in order to figure out why this is happening.

Comment: Process builder is immune to CPU time limit. it can run for longer than the 10K ms and then the next line of code that is hit will error. Is this the case here? Idea is package causes a DML and PB is fired then upon return to the controller bam, CPU time limit exceeded

Comment: @Eric Excellent point, that. PB can easily run that long without causing a timeout until you get back into Apex Code territory.

Comment: @eric and sfdcfox, thanks for input. I have de-activated all the workflow rules and process builder flows and I still see the error. Although the processbuilder and workflow rules are now contributing to a negligible percent of time, I just deactivated every single one of them to rule them out.

Comment: Can you include a screenshot? Real time elapsed can be significantly more than CPU Time consumed.

Comment: I would like to add that APEX_CODE in debug does not equal to CPU time. You can only get actual CPU time passed at the end of the log (with corresponding log levels) or through Limits.getCPUTime();
APEX_CODE time is usually way larger that actual limit CPU time.
This particular request with 35,256 APEX_TIME can be below 10,000 CPU time limit.

Comment: @Andrei.Z, apart from screenshot, in the execution logs, at the bottom where it displays stack trace, it reads the <methodname> executed 1 time in 13000ms.

Comment: @Venkata That is still not the CPU time. Again CPU time can only be seen with Limits.getCPUTime();  or in the end of the log with corresponding debug level for apex code, and it will look like LIMIT_USAGE_FOR_NS   Maximum CPU time: X out of 10000

Comment: @Venkata if we are talking about execution time then limit is 10 minutes , again this is different from CPU time

Comment: @Andrei.Z: that makes sense as managed packages have thier own limits