# CPU time limit 10000 and FLOW_ELEMENT_LIMIT_USAGE CPU limit is 15000

Tags: governorlimits, cpulimit, cpu-time

Today i was debugging the CPU timeout error due to Flow execution and saw two type of CPU limits :-

1. FLOW_ELEMENT_LIMIT_USAGE: This has statement "`|FLOW_ELEMENT_LIMIT_USAGE|2 ms CPU time, total 14465 out of 15000`" . What i can understand from this is maximum CPU limit is 15000 and till this branch transaction has consumed 14465 CPU time.
2. Then when the transaction ends All Governor limits and corresponding consumed units are shown, there again i can see `Maximum CPU time: 14687 out of 10000 ******* CLOSE TO LIMIT`. Here it says the CPU limit is 10000.

So now i am little confused about CPU Limit, can anyone please explain how this two are related and although both are CPU limit why both values are different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding item 2 - Salesforce allow to exceed the limit in some cases. It depends on some Salesforce consideration. See more details here: [Maximum CPU time limit allowed to be exceeded in Sandbox](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/48648/maximum-cpu-time-limit-allowed-to-be-exceeded-in-sandbox)

Regarding item 1 - it is the usage only for the flow. It seems that Salesforce allocate to the flow 15000 ms, although at the end it is being count under the total transaction limits (10000).